# Opening all the dropdown menu's through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am looking to open all the dropdowns for this webpage to then access all the href's to the various subcategory webpages. My issue is I am unsure on how to iteratively do this due to dynamic nature of the webpage and trouble accessing the dropdowns to begin with.

My code is attached below iterating through the top layer of categories and successfully pulling the hrefs. The website is found via the URL object for recreation of the problem. Any kind of assistance or feedback is appreciated.

*The end goal is to eventually access all these subcategories and access the various "items" on each page such as each individual Bag on the first subcategory. *

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


URL = "https://albiononline2d.com/en/item"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
driver.get(URL)
action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)

item_categories = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'list-group')


def categories():
    """Scrapes all the top categories of the website"""
    item_list =[]
    for items in item_categories:
        elements = items.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')
        for el in elements:
            item_list.append(el.get_attribute('href'))
    return item_list
```

Attached below is a snippet of the elements showing the List of all the accessed elements (Parent categories)
[Various elements that need to be iterated through.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0RJU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. Firstly you need to open up to categories. Then get all the links filtered by a substring "subcat".

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from time import sleep


URL = "https://albiononline2d.com/en/item"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.implicitly_wait(0.5)
driver.get(URL)
action = webdriver.ActionChains(driver)


pluses = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="icon expand-icon ion-plus-round"]')

for i in range(len(pluses)):
    np = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="icon expand-icon ion-plus-round"]')
    np[0].click()


item_categories = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'list-group')[0]

links = item_categories.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'a')

subcat_links = []
for link in links:
    if 'subcat' in link.get_attribute('href'):
        subcat_links.append(link.get_attribute('href'))
```

`subcat_links` will contain the result.